# Parallelism static job with static work assignment

Tags: kubernetes

This [document](https://github.com/eBay/Kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/jobs.md#job-patterns) describes options for running parallel jobs. The one I'm interested in is "Single job with static work assignment" Where I would create a job, set parallelism > 0 and completions == count of my work items.
The problem is, I don't know how would the pods know which item they should process? environment variables look identical... not sure if k8s passes some sequence number I can use... ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in your case is to use some MQ services.
Your actions order may be the next:

- Start MQ service
- Create a queue and fill it with messages
- Start a Job that works on tasks from the queue

Here you can find the latest documentation on [Job Patterns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-patterns).
Also look at kube examples that you can find [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/#running-the-job) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/).
In these examples/tasks, Kubernetes uses RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I understand standing up an MQ service is one of the options laid out in the link I posted. I, however, specifically want to ask about the static work assignment option..

Comment: Unfortunately, Kubernetes cannot pass that information to the job. Like I wrote before, use some external tools like MQ.